# Como posso garantir que minha API será usada apenas os recursos que desejo que ele use?

Tags: laravel, api, oauth2, oauth

Olá, tenho a seguinte dúvida.

Tenho uma aplicação que será utilizada por diversas empresas,cada empresa terá um número de funcionários(usuários apenas da empresa) e tenho usuários comuns(clientes das empresas). O relacionamento do sistema está em uma única estrutura de N:N e N:1. A ideia principal é cada empresa manipular seus próprios recursos, individualmente sem poder alterar empresas terceiras. Já os usuários podem utilizar todos recursos da empresa (empresas onde ele está relacionado). Minha dúvida seria referente a exposição dessa API, como posso garantir que um usuário malicioso com essa URI exposta não acesse, manipule recursos de outras empresas. Apenas quero que quando ele acessar a empresa X , ele consiga apenas utilizar os endpoints da empresa X, da mesma forma os usuários(clientes das empresas) acessem a empresa Y e só manipulem recursos que estão dentro da empresa Y.

Vi que existe o protocolo de autenticação OAuth2,que protege nossa API , eu deveria criar um Client OAuth2 para cada empresa verificando se ele está utilizando apenas essa empresa?

Estou meio confuso enquanto a isso. Se conseguiu entender o que falei acima , pode me ajudar? hahaha

Estou utilizando Laravel e Laravel Passport.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor forma para isso é que todo lançamento de por exemplo: Clientes / Pessoas / Empresas / Produtos / Pedidos vá o id da empresa a que esse usuário pertence. Então você cria uma verificação usando o Middleware que se caso o id não bater receberá um acesso negado.

Comment: Obrigado man , talvez isso ajude mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é usar uma estratégia multi-tenant ou multi-tenancy, nessa abordagem um dos métodos é você separar os dados de cada empresa em bancos de dados diferentes mas usando uma só aplicação.

Mas existem outras abordagens, aqui tem um artigo que explora o uso de multi-tenant com Laravel.

https://medium.com/@ashokgelal/a-full-featured-multi-tenant-app-with-laravel-part-1-4049a3cc229d

Comment: Mais um artigo sobre o assunto https://laravel-news.com/tenancy